# Firebase Cloud Messaging - failure registration list

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver notifications to my Android client apps, each notification should be sent to a all devices...

I am using PHP to send notification...
But problem is that if i send notification on 500 devices, 
I get response

```
{
  "multicast_id": 5.52490057,
  "success": 400,
  "failure": 100,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": => array(2) 
    { [0]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> string(19) "InvalidRegistration" } 
      [1]=> array(1) { ["message_id"]=> "0:1213"}
    }
}
```

All 500 Registration tokes are save in my DB.

> I want list of 100 fail registration ids, so i can remove them from my
>   database...

I search on google also check in FCM documentation, but i find nothing..

I have idea: Send notification on all devices one by one in loop, so i can know which device is not found, But i want proper way to do this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Think that you should get in response array containing all failed cases?
You are sending notification by HTTP?

Comment: Yes i am sending notification by HTTP, but i get only number of success/fail response. I want list of fail ids...